# Timezone in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

My computer time zone `'Asia/Tashkent'`. And I set Yii2 time zone to `'Asia/Tashkent'` too in config. But Yii2 is still displaying time incorrectly. I am wondering what I have missed?

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); 
echo $time;  // 2018-03-07 14:10:57
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($time, 'medium'); // 7:10:57 PM
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($time, 'medium'); // Mar 7, 2018
echo date_default_timezone_get(); // Asia/Tashkent
```

Comment: What will happen if you add `Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = 'Asia/Tashkent';` before echoing time?

Comment: do you mean the `date_default_timezone_get();` is returning the right timezone but you are getting incorrect time

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam you got it correctly. Timezone is correct but displaying diffirent time. 5 hours difference

Comment: No no, what will display `Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($time, 'medium')` if you my code before echoing time.

Comment: #Yupic nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are giving `asTime()` string date formatter assumes it's in default timezone which by default in Yii 2 is UTC.

If you want this to be the same as the output of PHP `date()` change the default timezone in Yii to yours. For example in the configuration:

```
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
        'class'           => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'Asia/Tashkent',
    ],
],
```