# How to display time in Yii2 depending on the client's time zone?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, timezone

How to display time in Yii2 depending on the client's time zone?

I'm using PostgreSQL and save the date in timestamp without time zone. Time zone parameters in PostgreSQL config file equal to UTC. Yii2 app config doesn't include time zone params.

I don't want to change all existing models. I want to set a time zone for session time only and for all models (globally). I do not want to use "Yii::$app->formatter" in every view.

I need to get DateTime data from the database in UTC format and display it in client's time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148140/timezone-in-yii2)

Comment: Do you know client timezone at PHP level?

Comment: Yes, I do. I detect it when the user login.